# Short-lived sci-fi series with a former astronaut turned superhero (or maybe a police officer?) using his spacesuit for his "powers"

Tags: story-identification, tv

**Plot Details/Summary**

I only watched an episode or two of this one, so I can't recall a whole lot about it.  The protagonist is a former astronaut of some sort, who makes it his mission to clean up the crime in his city.  He might have been a police officer in his "new life" or he might have decided to become a sort of quasi-superhero.  In either case, I distinctly recall his space suit being the gimmick that makes him an effective crime fighter in the show.  I seem to recall the protagonist being a young, dark-haired man, and I think he had a friendship or an alliance with a young woman (maybe a fellow cop, or someone from the space program?).  I don't think there were alien beings in the show.   The criminal threats were all quite terrestrial, IIRC.

**Timeframe and other Publication Details**

This was a syndicated tv show I saw on American television, probably around the late 90s to early 2000's.  I believe the show was filmed in Canada, though I'm not certain.  I don't think it lasted very long - it was pretty dreadful.  I can say for certain the show is not *Space Cop* or Gerry Anderson's *Space Precinct*.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Green Lantern, except that was a film.

Comment: Reminds me of the 1970's TV series _The Greatest American Hero_, except the protagonist, Ralph Hinckley, was a blond high-school teacher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like [***Super Force***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Force)

> Super Force is an American action-adventure TV series which aired from October 1990 to May 1992.
>
> The series is about a **former astronaut turned cop** who uses a **highly advanced combat armor** and motorcycle to fight crime in the city of Metroplex during the future year 2020. Among the features of the black battle suit were enhanced strength and armament and a force field that protected the wearer from virtually all known weapons, whereas the motorcycle had an array of James Bond-type gadgets and weapons.

[image: man in a black suit, holding a large gun]

Comment: Featuring *Larry B Scott* who voiced the Paladin in Diablo 2 :-)

Comment: Wow, wasn't this a surprisingly topical question: "during the future year 2020". 

Comment: That's definitely the show I was trying to remember!